# Searching couch db based on dynamic selector query

Tags: couchdb, node-modules

I have been trying to use https://github.com/wearetheledger/node-couchdb-query-engine for querying the couchdb based on the selector query which would be supplied  by the UI based on the action the user makes.

the code below used in the library takes cars as a constant which in my case need to be on the actual couchdb. the secord parameter (the selector one would be supplied from the UI)
const filteredResult = queryEngine.parseQuery( cars, {selector:{year:{$gt:2016}}} )

The main issue is i want the first parameter (cars here) to be a kind of db connection on which the selector query gets applied.

Regards,
Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

The code you're trying to use is just providing a SearchInterface on a Javascript object.

If you want to use dynamic queries on CouchDB, you can do it natively with the Mango.

Since you're using NodeJS, you could use the official NodeJS library client for CouchDB:

Nano: https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano

Code example:

```
const nano = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984');
nano.db.create('alice');
const alice = nano.db.use('alice');
/ find documents where the name = "Brian" and age > 25.
const q = {
  selector: {
    name: { "$eq": "Brian"},
    age : { "$gt": 25 }
  },
  fields: [ "name", "age", "tags", "url" ],
  limit:50
};
alice.find(q).then((doc) => {
  console.log(doc);
});
```